# Request timeout when soap12 is malformated

Tags: servicestack

We use Servicestack 5.9.2 and get the following error in the log file when sending an malformated soap message. The soap request runs in a timeout. What do we have to do, that the request gets a response with an error message?

```
2021-10-01 09:10:43,356 DEBUG: Comp.Webservice.Utils.BaseService.LogCount: Request type: Get Documentations, json: {OnlyChanged:True,Type:CarePlan,SubTypeIds:[0],CustomerIds:[1004],From:2020-01-01,To:2022-01-01,Limit:1}, returning: 0 objects
2021-10-01 09:10:43,683 DEBUG: Comp.ServiceStackAppHost+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__2: stop 0
2021-10-01 09:11:01,890 DEBUG: Comp.ServiceStackAppHost+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__1: start 1
2021-10-01 09:11:01,891 DEBUG: Comp.ServiceStackAppHost+<>c.<ConfigurePlugins>b__23_2: POST /soap12
2021-10-01 09:11:01,945 ERROR: Comp.ServiceStackAppHost.LogToLogger: Error processing: http://localhost:8183/api/soap12
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: DeserializeDataContract: Error converting type: DeserializeDataContract: Error converting type: Der ungültige Aufzählungswert "39" kann nicht in den Typ "Comp.Dto.DocumentationType" deserialisiert werden. Stellen Sie sicher, dass die erforderlichen Aufzählungswerte vorhanden und mit dem Attribut "EnumMemberAttribute" gekennzeichnet sind, wenn der Typ das Attribut "DataContractAttribute" aufweist. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: DeserializeDataContract: Error converting type: Der ungültige Aufzählungswert "39" kann nicht in den Typ "Comp.Dto.DocumentationType" deserialisiert werden. Stellen Sie sicher, dass die erforderlichen Aufzählungswerte vorhanden und mit dem Attribut "EnumMemberAttribute" gekennzeichnet sind, wenn der Typ das Attribut "DataContractAttribute" aufweist. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Der ungültige Aufzählungswert "39" kann nicht in den Typ "Comp.Dto.DocumentationType" deserialisiert werden. Stellen Sie sicher, dass die erforderlichen Aufzählungswerte vorhanden und mit dem Attribut "EnumMemberAttribute" gekennzeichnet sind, wenn der Typ das Attribut "DataContractAttribute" aufweist.
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumDataContract.ReadEnumValue(String value, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumDataContract.ReadEnumValue(XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
   bei ReadGetDocumentationsFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   bei ServiceStack.Text.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(String xml, Type type)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei ServiceStack.Text.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(String xml, Type type)
   bei ServiceStack.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.DeserializeFromString(String xml, Type type)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei ServiceStack.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.DeserializeFromString(String xml, Type type)
   bei ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.SoapHandler.<ExecuteMessage>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Soap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap12:Body>
      <GetDocumentations xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Comp" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <CustomerIds xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <d2p1:int>1004</d2p1:int>
         </CustomerIds>
         <From>2020-01-01T00:00:00</From>
         <Limit>1</Limit>
         <OnlyChanged>true</OnlyChanged>
         <SubTypeIds xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <d2p1:int>0</d2p1:int>
         </SubTypeIds>
         <To>2022-01-01T00:00:00</To>
         <Type>39</Type>
      </GetDocumentations>
   </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

In that case 39 is wrong. 39 has to be enum xy and it works.

Any idea is to redefine our UncaughtExceptionHandlers to build a response and end the request. Something like this:

```
            UncaughtExceptionHandlers.Add((req, res, operationName, ex) =>
            {
                // write to logfile
                //build response
                res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                res.EndRequest();
            });
```

Is that how this should be handled? If yes, does somebody have a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Please see docs on [SOAP Exceptions](https://docs.servicestack.net/soap-support#soap-exceptions), we recommend sending the error with a 200 OK Response and the Error Message serialized in the `ResponseStatus` property of the Response DTO.

Answer (score 0):

That answer does not help. We already have that ServiceExceptionHandlers, but the request does not run through that code. It runs into the UncaughtExceptionHandlers. The documentation says to UncaughtExceptionHandlers:

```
    //Handle Unhandled Exceptions occurring outside of Services
    //E.g. Exceptions during Request binding or in filters:
```

That sounds like it is the correct method for a malformated Soap Message. In this method I tried:

```
    if (req.GetItem(Keywords.SoapMessage) is System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message requestMsg)
    {
        req.Response.UseBufferedStream = true;
        var msgVersion = requestMsg.Version;
        using (var response = XmlWriter.Create(req.Response.OutputStream))
        {
            var message = System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(
                msgVersion, new FaultCode("Receiver"), ex.ToString(), null);
            message.WriteMessage(response);
        }
        req.Response.End();
    }
```

but that does not work, because req.GetItem(Keywords.SoapMessage) is null.

So how does the correct handling look like?

Comment: If ServiceStack is unable to deserialize the request it wont have a Request SOAP message, you'll need a different way to identify that it's a SOAP request, e.g. by looking at the Request PathInfo. Since you don't `requestMsg` you can `MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004` for SOAP 1.2 or `MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004` for SOAP 1.1 as the `msgVersion`. Here's some [static methods that show serializing SOAP Response Messages](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/c9373efa16f906f1f699399b908036cd6a23ace7/src/ServiceStack/Host/Handlers/SoapHandler.cs#L258-L266).